# conditions to chain bash scripts with puppet

Tags: puppet

I am new to puppet and I have two questions. I want to execute 2 successive  custom bash scripts:

```
file{ 'deploy_0':
  ensure => 'file',
  path => '/home/user_name/scripts/deploy_0.sh',
  ...
  notify => Exec['deploy_core']
}

file{ 'deploy_1':
  ensure => 'file',
  path => '/home/user_name/scripts/deploy_1.sh',
  ...
  notify => Exec['deploy_core_api']
}

exec { 'deploy_core':
  command => '/bin/bash -c "/home/user_name/scripts/deploy_0"',
}

exec { 'deploy_core_api':
  command => '/bin/bash -c "/home/user_name/scripts/deploy_1.sh"',
  onlyif => 'deploy_core'
}
```

But this does not work

I know I can put for the `onlyif` paramter a bash command such as `/bin/bash -c "/home/user_name/scripts/deploy_0.sh`, but I prefer to declare a `file` resource.

Answer (score 1):

You used the `notify` metaparameters correctly and well to specify the scripts needed to be deployed before execution (`file` before corresponding `exec`) and should be executed again if the file content changes. You need similar metaparameters for application order on the `exec` resources if you want similar functionality there. Note that `onlyif` is an `exec` attribute that executes a local command on the client and causes the resource to be considered already in sync (not applied due to idempotence) during catalog application if it returns something falsey.

Since you do not need refreshing here from one `exec` to the other like you did with the `file` resource, we can use `require` or `before` instead.

```
# before
exec { 'deploy_core':
  command => '/bin/bash -c "/home/user_name/scripts/deploy_0"',
  before  => File['deploy_core_api'],
}

exec { 'deploy_core_api':
  command => '/bin/bash -c "/home/user_name/scripts/deploy_1.sh"',
}

# require
exec { 'deploy_core':
  command => '/bin/bash -c "/home/user_name/scripts/deploy_0"',
}

exec { 'deploy_core_api':
  command => '/bin/bash -c "/home/user_name/scripts/deploy_1.sh"',
  require => File['deploy_core'],
}
```

This will give you the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: Although "causes the resource to be ignored during catalog application if it returns something falsey" is a correct description of the effect of `Exec.onlyif`, a more useful one would be "causes the resource to be *considered already in sync* during catalog application [...]".  That provides a better basis for understanding other associated behaviors.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Good call; updating answer